# Retrieve results from multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

This is my first post so hello there all!

Wondering could I get a bit of help with getting my results out of this md array? Its giving me unexpected results. I have looked for answers but am not sure what question I should be asking..

This is a sample of the relevant part of the array [using `var_dump`]:

```
["Attendee"] => array(11) 
                  { 
                    ["id"]=> int(148) 
                    ["firstname"]=> string(5) "dave" 
                    ["lastname"]=> string(6) "davey"`
                  }
```

This is my foreach code to get the first and last names for each attendee:

```
foreach ($the_info_array['body']['Registrations'] as $registrations)
{
    foreach ($registrations as $regvalue)
    {
        echo $regvalue['firstname'].” “.$regvalue['lastname'];
    }
    echo “<br>”;
}
```

**This prints:**

```
a a2 2 5 5 dave davey
a a2 2 5 5 scott davey
a a2 2 5 5 bill davey
```

etc

**rather than what i want ie:**

```
dave davey
scott davey
bill davey
```

Where am i going wrong, & what are the extra characters?
Thanks in advance for any kind help the community can give!

**EDIT>>**

Strangely, if I change the echo to

```
echo $regvalue['firstname'];
```

it prints:

```
a25dave
a25scott
a25bill
```

and

echo $regvalue['firstname']." ";

prints

```
a 2 5 dave
a 2 5 scott
a 2 5 bill
```

Here is the complete array minus several records as I can't seem to post that many characters:

```
array(3) { 
    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" 
    ["status_code"]=> int(200) 
    ["body"]=> array(1) { 
        ["Registrations"]=> array(12) { 
            [0]=> array(15) { 
                ["id"]=> int(148) 
                ["status"]=> string(8) "approved" 
                ["date_of_registration"]=> string(19) "2013-12-04 12:43:31" 
                ["final_price"]=> int(0) 
                ["code"]=> string(23) "529f2373bb7555.08033147" 
                ["url_link"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["is_primary"]=> bool(true) 
                ["is_group_registration"]=> bool(true) 
                ["is_going"]=> bool(true) 
                ["is_checked_in"]=> bool(false) 
                ["Event"]=> array(14) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(531) ["code"]=> string(15) "1-5298c3675e610" 
                    ["name"]=> string(21) "Recital 2014" 
                    ["description"]=> string(721) "The Description is this!" 
                    ["status"]=> string(6) "active" 
                    ["limit"]=> int(280) 
                    ["group_registrations_allowed"]=> bool(true) 
                    ["group_registrations_max"]=> int(50) 
                    ["active"]=> bool(true) 
                    ["member_only"]=> bool(false) 
                    ["virtual_url"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["call_in_number"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["phone"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["metadata"]=> array(9) { 
                        ["default_payment_status"]=> string(10) "Incomplete" 
                        ["venue_id"]=> int(1) 
                        ["additional_attendee_reg_info"]=> string(1) "1" 
                        ["add_attendee_question_groups"]=> array(1) { 
                            [1]=> string(1) "1" } 
                        ["date_submitted"]=> string(10) "29/11/2013" 
                        ["event_hashtag"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["event_format"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["event_livestreamed"]=> string(0) "" 
                        [""]=> string(0) "" } } 
                ["Attendee"]=> array(11) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(219) 
                    ["firstname"]=> string(5) “dave” 
                    [“lastname”]=> string(7) "davis" 
                    ["address"]=> string(13) "10 The Street" 
                    ["address2"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["city"]=> string(8) "The City" 
                    ["state"]=> string(10) "The County" 
                    ["country"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["zip"]=> string(6) "BN66YY" 
                    ["email"]=> string(17) "mail@webhost.com" 
                    ["phone"]=> string(12) "012736654432" } 
                ["Transaction"]=> array(9) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(219) 
                    ["timestamp"]=> string(19) "2013-12-23 00:26:22" 
                    ["total"]=> float(132.6) 
                    ["amount_paid"]=> int(0) 
                    ["status"]=> string(10) "incomplete" 
                    ["details"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["tax_data"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["session_data"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["payment_gateway"]=> string(19) "Credit / Debit Card" } 
                ["Datetime"]=> array(8) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(0) ["is_primary"]=> bool(true) 
                    ["event_start"]=> string(19) "2014-01-11 00:00:00" 
                    ["event_end"]=> string(19) "2014-01-11 00:00:00" 
                    ["registration_start"]=> string(19) "2012-08-12 16:00:00" 
                    ["registration_end"]=> string(19) "2014-01-10 16:00:00" 
                    ["limit"]=> int(280) ["tickets_left"]=> int(274) } 
                ["Price"]=> array(9) { 
                    ["id"]=> int(0) 
                    ["name"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["amount"]=> int(0) 
                    ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
                    ["limit"]=> int(9999999) 
                    ["remaining"]=> int(999999) 
                    ["start_date"]=> NULL 
                    ["end_date"]=> NULL 
                    ["Pricetype"]=> array(8) { 
                        ["id"]=> int(1) 
                        ["name"]=> string(10) "Base Price" 
                        ["is_member"]=> bool(false) 
                        ["is_discount"]=> bool(false) 
                        ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) 
                        ["is_percent"]=> bool(false) 
                        ["is_global"]=> bool(true) 
                        ["order"]=> int(0) } } } } } }
```

// Also, don't know if relevant, but the array comes from a json decode originally

Comment: can you post the array?

Comment: Its not really possible to see the error when we dont see the array, Can you add the complete array to the question?

Comment: Post the array please.

Comment: If `$regvalue` is the attendee array then the output you're seeing isn't possible with the code you've provided. What happens if you comment out the first echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your looping over each array inside registrations even though most of these are not an attendee (i.e `$regvalue` will be an id in the first loop status in the second loop e.t.c.).

Try:

```
foreach ($the_info_array['body']['Registrations'] as $registrations)
{
        echo $registrations['Attendee']['firstname']." ".$registrations['Attendee']['lastname'];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: OK I see now, makes sense now you point it out, work perfectly, many thanks